# What are possible algorithm for converting a 24-bit ".bmp" image to black and white/Monochrome image?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a **coloured 24 bit depth image** to **monochrome/blackandwhite image**.So,there are two parts of image (i.e) *Headers(Bitmap file header & DIB header) and Pixel array*

**First part(HEADERS)** .Here is the code to calculate both the header of monochrome image to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5WcG.png) *Is there any other good method I can calculate headers??*

```
int nBitmapImageWidth = pBMPstructure->fngetBitmapwidth();//Structure which returm the image width
int nRowSize = ((nBitmapImageWidth + 31) / 32) * 4;//Calculation of row size 
int nSizeRawBitmap = nRowSize * (pBMPstructure->fngetBitmapheight());
int nSizeBMP = nSizeRawBitmap + 62;
//Bitmap file header starts
bReadBuffer[0] = pBMPstructure->fngetFiletype();
bReadBuffer[2] = nSizeBMP;//Error Debugging
bReadBuffer[6] = pBMPstructure->fngetReserved1();
bReadBuffer[8] = pBMPstructure->fngetReserved2();
bReadBuffer[10] = 0x3E;
//Bitmap file header ends
//DIB Header starts
bReadBuffer[14] = 0x28;
bReadBuffer[18] = nBitmapImageWidth;
bReadBuffer[22] = pBMPstructure->fngetBitmapheight();
bReadBuffer[26] = pBMPstructure->fngetColorplanes(); bReadBuffer[28] = 1; 
bReadBuffer[30] = pBMPstructure->fngetCompressionmethod();
bReadBuffer[34] = nSizeRawBitmap;//Error Debugging
bReadBuffer[38] = pBMPstructure->fngetHorizontalresolution(); 
bReadBuffer[42] = pBMPstructure->fngetVerticalresolution();
bReadBuffer[46] = pBMPstructure->fngetColorpalette(); 
bReadBuffer[50] = pBMPstructure->fngetImportantcolors();
bReadBuffer[54] = 0x00; bReadBuffer[55] = 0x00; bReadBuffer[56] = 0x00; 
bReadBuffer[57] = 0x00;
bReadBuffer[58] = 0xff; bReadBuffer[59] = 0xff; 
bReadBuffer[60] = 0xff; bReadBuffer[61] = 0x00;
//DIB Header ends
//End of creating header for black and white
```

**Second part(PIXEL ARRAY)** .Here is the code for calculating pixel array [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLE12.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElKgQ.png) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsXP8.png).

```
//Calculation of pixel array for black and white image/Monochrome begins
            DWORD bsizeofBMP = pBMPstructure->fngetSizeBMP();
            bsizeofBMP -= obj_BMP.fnreturnOffsetpixelarray();
            int nSectors = (bsizeofBMP - obj_BMP.fnreturnOffsetpixelarray()) / nLineLengthColoured;
            int nFlagHeader = 1, nFlagPixelArray = 1;
            if (obj_file_to_read.fnCreate(argv[2], GENERIC_READ, OPEN_EXISTING) == FALSE)//Creating a handle to Source image file
            {
                dwErrCode = GetLastError();//Retriving the last error code
                _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error message:-%ws\n"), obj_error_handler.fngeterrordescription(dwErrCode));//Retriving error message
                _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error code:-%d"), obj_error_handler.fngetErrCode());//Retriving error code
                _tprintf(_T("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if (obj_file_to_write.fnCreate(argv[3], GENERIC_WRITE, CREATE_ALWAYS) == FALSE)//Craeting a handle to destination image file
            {
                dwErrCode = GetLastError();//Retriving the last error code
                _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error message:-%ws"), obj_error_handler.fngeterrordescription(dwErrCode));//Retriving error message
                _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error code:-%d"), obj_error_handler.fngetErrCode());//Retriving error code
                _tprintf(_T("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            while (nSectors)
            {
                if (nFlagHeader == 1)//So that pointer goes only one times inside this very code
                {
                    if (obj_file_to_write.fnWrite(bReadBuffer, 62) == FALSE)//To write HEADERS to destination file
                    {
                        obj_file_to_write.fnClose();//Closing the handle opened for writing to the file
                        dwErrCode = GetLastError();//Retriving the last error code
                        _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error message:-%ws\n"), obj_error_handler.fngeterrordescription(dwErrCode));//Retriving error message
                        _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error code:-%d"), obj_error_handler.fngetErrCode());//Retriving error code
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    }
                    --nFlagHeader;
                }
                BYTE bNewReadBuffer[4096] = { 0 };//Creating a new array to load one line of source file
                if (nFlagPixelArray == 1)//For first iteration need to set the file pointer to after both headers so that it is not overwritten
                {
                    DWORD dwptr = SetFilePointer(obj_file_to_read.fnGetHandle(), obj_BMP.fnreturnOffsetpixelarray(), NULL, FILE_BEGIN);//SetFilePointer WinAPI
                    if (dwptr == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)//Check if it is pointing to the desired or giving some garbage value
                    {
                        dwErrCode = GetLastError();//Retriving the last error code
                        _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error message:-%ws\n"), obj_error_handler.fngeterrordescription(dwErrCode));//Retriving error message
                        _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error code:-%d"), obj_error_handler.fngetErrCode());//Retriving error code
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    }
                    --nFlagPixelArray;//Decrementing so that it will no enter in this part of code
                }
                if (obj_file_to_read.fnRead(bNewReadBuffer, nLineLengthColoured) == FALSE)
                {
                    obj_file_to_read.fnClose();
                    obj_file_to_write.fnClose();
                    dwErrCode = GetLastError();//Retriving the last error code
                    _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error message:-%ws\n"), obj_error_handler.fngeterrordescription(dwErrCode));
                    _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error code:-%d"), obj_error_handler.fngetErrCode());//Retriving error code
                    _tprintf(_T("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                BYTE bMonoBuffer[128] = { 0 };//It is the buffer which is made for storing single line of black and white image
                int nMonoBytes = ((nLineLengthColoured - nPaddingColoured) / 3) / (nLineLengthBlackAndWhite - nPaddingBlackAndWhite);//3 is BGR values and calculating rthe sectors
                int nMonoAdditional = ((nLineLengthColoured - nPaddingColoured) / 3) % (nLineLengthBlackAndWhite - nPaddingBlackAndWhite);//Calculating the additional bytes which is remaining after calculating the sectors
                int nIteratorbNewReadBuffer = 0;
                while (nMonoBytes)//nMonoBytes specifies how many times will the bMonoBuffer will be filled
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < (nLineLengthBlackAndWhite - nPaddingBlackAndWhite); i++)//Loop started for the amount of 1 line which is to be feeded inside the monochrome image
                    {
                        bMonoBuffer[i] = (bNewReadBuffer[nIteratorbNewReadBuffer] + bNewReadBuffer[nIteratorbNewReadBuffer + 1] + bNewReadBuffer[nIteratorbNewReadBuffer + 2]) / 3;//Algorithm for conversion from bgr value to monochrome/black ad white i.e the average of all the three value
                        nIteratorbNewReadBuffer += 3;//Incrementing the iterator for bNewReadBuffer which is containg one single line of coloured BMP
                    }
                    if (nPaddingBlackAndWhite != 0)//if padding of black and whiote is not zero
                    {
                        for (int i = (nLineLengthBlackAndWhite - nPaddingBlackAndWhite); i < nLineLengthBlackAndWhite; i++)//from the position where data of black and white image ends   
                        {
                            bMonoBuffer[i] = 00;
                        }
                    }
                    if (obj_file_to_write.fnWrite(bMonoBuffer, nLineLengthBlackAndWhite) == FALSE)
                    {
                        obj_file_to_read.fnClose();
                        obj_file_to_write.fnClose();
                        dwErrCode = GetLastError();//Retriving the last error code
                        _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error message:-%ws\n"), obj_error_handler.fngeterrordescription(dwErrCode));//Retriving error message
                        _tprintf(_T("\n\tThe error code:-%d"), obj_error_handler.fngetErrCode());//Retriving error code
                        _tprintf(_T("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    }
                    nMonoBytes--;
                }
                if (nMonoAdditional != 0)//The remaining bytes
                {//Problem here is that the last remaining bytes will be of certain bytes and will be copied to destination but when next iteration starts it will continue 
                    //to convert the whole line for monobytes instead it should be the new bytes have to be readed minus the additional one already readed..
                    for (int i = 0; i < nMonoAdditional; i++)
                    {
                        bMonoBuffer[i] = (bNewReadBuffer[nIteratorbNewReadBuffer] + bNewReadBuffer[nIteratorbNewReadBuffer + 1] + bNewReadBuffer[nIteratorbNewReadBuffer + 2]) / 3;
                    }
                    nMonoAdditional--;
                }
                nSectors--;
            }
```

**For example(.bmp image)**

Let say that there is a coloured image of size **1,131,654 bytes** and as we know that **54 bytes** will be it's *headers* size. When I subtract the header part from the image size then pixel array size of coloured will be **1,131,600 bytes** and there can some *padding bytes*,let suppose padding of coloured is **3 bytes** and length of one line of coloured image is **2460 bytes** and total lines in the image will be **460 lines**.The desired image is monochrome image which have linelength of **104 bytes** and padding bytes is **2 bytes**.So,if I take **1...2457 bytes**(ignoring the padding bytes)then,there will be **2457/3=819 BGR pairs** means if I write each pair to my desired file(i.e,black and white) then it will take **819 pairs * 460 lines = 3,76,740 bytes**, but the desired file should be of **47,840+62=47,902** size!!

1. First thing first,the error in debugging 389 and 399 in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5WcG.png) image.And is there any better method than this if yes what is it?
2. Second thing second,Problem here is that the last remaining bytes will be of certain bytes and will be copied to destination but when next iteration starts it will continue to convert the whole line for monobytes instead it should be the new bytes have to be readed minus the additional one already readed..as in [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsXP8.png) image line number 125,126,127 commented problem.
3. What is the algorithm to convert coloured to black and white apart from taking average.

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: I have added code

Comment: Hi Shubham. A couple of tips for working on Stack Overflow: 1) The rule is, one question / Question - you ask three, which automatically makes this "too broad" even though you have added the code. Read up in the [help] about what this means and generally how to formulate questions that will be well-received. 2) In order to reply to people in comments so that they get a notification you need to "ping" them using the @ symbol. For example @cindymeister.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are a lot of questions here, most of them are unanswerable, because of lacking contexts. The only thing i can answer is why you have image data size of 376,740 bytes, rather than 47,840 bytes.

The 376,740 bytes is consistent with a 819x460 monochrome/grayscale image with 1 byte (= 8 bit) per pixel. But when we talk about "Black and white" image we often mean 1 *bit* per pixel. 819 bits per line gives us 819/8=102.375 bytes per scanline. Rounded up to an even number of bytes, we get 104 bytes per scanline. Multiplied by 460 scanlines, we get 47,840 bytes for the image data.